# Firebase Firestore: How to monitor read document count by collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm monitoring document read count in Firebase Console > Firestore > Usage section.

However, I want to find a way to see **document read count by collection** so that I can know which query to optimize.

Is there anyway for that?
I looked into GCP monitoring but I couldn't achieve what I want to do here.

I read documents from js SDK and nodejs Admin SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore provides no accounting other than a total running read count for the entire database for the last 30 days.  If you need something more specific, you'll have to record it yourself somehow.

Comment: Thank you.  I will consider counting documents each time I fetch data

Comment: Are there any examples of how one might "record it yourself somehow"?

Comment: @Nimai i personally don't see a feasible way, unless your insane and want to write to a document for each read. I would be very interested in some ability like the OP suggests though