# how to maintain read counts of documents in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[Firebase Firestore: How to monitor read document count by collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112274/firebase-firestore-how-to-monitor-read-document-count-by-collection)

So first of something similar like question was already asked almost a year ago so dont mark it duplicate cause I need some suggestions in detail.

So here is the scenario,

lets say I have some collections of database and in future I might need to perform some ML on the DB. According to the documents visit.

That is how many times a specific document is visited and for how much time.

I know the mentioned solution above indirectly suggests to perform a read followed by write operation to the database to append the read count every time I visit the database. **But it seems this needs to be done from client side**

Now if you see, lets say I have some documents and client is only allowed to read the document and not given with access for writing or updating. In this case either I will have to maintain a separate collection specifically to maintain the count, which is of course from client side or else I will have to expose a specific field in the parent document (actual documents from where I am showing the data to clients) to be write enabled and rest remaining field protected.

But fecthing this data from client side sounds an alarm for lot of things and parameters cause I want to collect this data even if the client is not authenticated.

I saw the documentation of cloud functions and it seems there is not trigger function which works as a watch dog for listening if the document is being fetched.

So I want some suggestions on how can we perform this in GCP by creating own custom trigger or hook in a server.

Just a head start will be so usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep track of read counts if you are using the Client SDKs. You would have to fetch data from Firestore with some secure env in the middle ([Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) or your own server).

A [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) like this may be useful:

```
// Returns data for the path passed in data obj
exports.getData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const snapshot = admin.firestore().doc(data.path).get()
  //Increment the read count
  await admin.firestore().collection("uesrs").doc(context.auth.uid).update({
    reads: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  })
  return snapshot.data()
});
```

Do note that you are using Firebase Admin SDK in this case which has complete access to all Firebase resources (bypasses all security rules). So you'll need to authorize the user yourself. You can get UID of user calling the function like this: `context.auth.uid` and then maybe some simple if-else logic will help.

Comment: Instead of fetching the data from cloud functions, what if I just make a trigger call from a onload function and pass only a document id from my client application, which basically starts a a watchdog on server side, and when the client leaves the document, i.e onDestroy, the watch dog will stop and update the count as well as watch time of that specific document.

Comment: But again it raises an concern, as I am collecting this data fom unauthenticated users. How can I stop the bots are trollers to avoid unnecessary calling of my functions.

Comment: @50_Seconds_Of_Coding the problem is you can't rely on client to keep the count updated. and without cloud functions or your server it's hard to keep track of it.  Maybe you can setup a small VM from [Google Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) and get an express app running where you won't be charged for invocations.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a Cloud Function in order to read or write from/to Firestore instead of directly interacting with Firestore from you front-end (with one of the Client SDKs).

This way you can keep one or more counters of the number of reads as well as calculate and apply specific access rights and everything is done **in the back-end**, not in the front-end.  With a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) you can get the user ID of authenticated users out of the box.

Note that by going through a Cloud Function you will loose some advantages of the Client SDKs, for example the ability to use a listener for real-time updates or the possibility to declare access rights through standard security rules. The following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c) covers the advantages and drawbacks of such approach.

Comment: Instead of fetching the data from cloud functions, what if I just make a trigger call from a onload function and pass only a document id from my client application, which basically starts a a watchdog on server side, and when the client leaves the document, i.e onDestroy, the watch dog will stop and update the count as well as watch time of that specific document.

Comment: But again it raises an concern, as I am collecting this data fom unauthenticated users. How can I stop the bots are trollers to avoid unnecessary calling of my functions.